# Android: Sometimes Firebase OnComplete callback is not getting called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Its a very weird issue with Firebase. I am calling setValue() on a Firebase node and then expecting OnComplete callback function to be called, which is never being called on a particular internet connection. Other firebase queries are also not working on that particular WiFi,

```
individualUserNode.setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

            if (databaseError == null) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvents.UserSaved(true));
            } else {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvents.UserSaved(false));
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's [expected](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener). The listener only fires once the server acknowledges the request:

> This interface is used as a method of being notified when an operation
>   has been acknowledged by the Database servers and can be considered
>   complete

Comment: Thanks SUPERCILEX. But, shouldn't there be an error callback (when it's timed out or any error has occurred) ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. The error is for the case where your rules denied the write, not some offline error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37190184/4548500 I would recommend adding a value event listener instead of a write complete listener.